# Can't access directive params in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
Vue.directive('selecttwo', {
  params: ['taskId'],
  bind: function () {
    var self = this;
    $(this.el)
      .select2()
      .on('change', function () {
        self.set(this.value);
        if (!this.name.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
            console.log('task-id->'+self.params.taskId); // task-id->undefined
        }
      })
  },
});
```

How can I get the `params.taskId` on `onchange` event? I already tried `this.params.taskId` , but I still get undefined.

Comment: unsure about that, but it may work adding the params.taskId as a parameter in your changehandler-function?! no time to test atm :)

Comment: just check your html attr name,use kebab-case like:"<span task-id='123' />"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can paste your html code,that will help to find issue.

I guess your html attribute name is incorrect,in vue,js use "camelCase",**but** html use "kebab-case",try like this:

```
<span task-id="i am id" v-selecttwo >
```